# k means produces empty clusters

Tags: k-means

I've implemented a k means clustering algorithm as described at http://faculty.uscupstate.edu/atzacheva/SHIM450/KMeansExample.doc

For some datasets I find that the number of clusters generated do not always equal initial k. Is this to be expected?

I think it is to be expected as after each iteration each data point is added to the closest cluster, but this does not guarantee that all clusters will be populated. Each cluster is reinitialised after each iteration so some clusters may not be sufficiently close to points to have any point added to them.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Are you taking the first K centroids from the set of objects? They should be random objects (from the set) but NOT random coordinates.

Comment: @Tilo I'm taking random k centroids from the set of objects, the coordinates are selected from the random points chosen. The coordinates themselves are not random.

Comment: @Tilo please see question update

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! I have been using variations of that algorithm for quite some time and never had empty clusters, but that is probably just some property of the data I'm working with.

Comment: @Tilo dataset I'm working with is very sparse and each point is relatively close in distance which may have be causing points to not be added to all clusters .

Comment: You should probably undo the edit and paste the link and the quote as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper describes that empty clusters for k means can occur http://www.academypublisher.com/ijrte/vol01/no01/ijrte0101220226.pdf

> One of the major problems of the k-means algorithm is that it may
>   produce empty clusters depending on initial center vectors. For static
>   execution of the k-means, this problem is considered insignificant and
>   can be solved by executing the algorithm for a number of times.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, so whenever I find an empty cluster, I simply redo kmeans. Most of the times it gets resolved.

Comment: @tuxdna In my experience as value of K increases then probability of empty clusters being generated also increases.

Comment: Another observation I have had is, occurrence of empty clusters is higher in reduced dimension, while keeping the number of samples and K same as with original dimensions. That is just an observation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as yours on image processing. I wish my experience could give you some hint...

I was trying to do a kmeans algorithm on an image whose original size is 720*1280, and the number of cluster is 10.

However, I feel this is too large so I (stupidly) used Gaussian Pyramid to compress this image into 144*256.

Then, after running the kmeans and reach to a convergence, I found almost 5 more clusters set are empty.

I tried to modify my algorithm like: if the cluster is empty then I will assign a new pixel as center and try again, or divide the largest cluster set.

Finally, I realized if there is empty cluster, it only means that whether the cluster number is not correct(as you can see unlike density-based clustering, k-means needs you to assign cluster number as parameter, and the value is important.) or the dataset you used is not big enough.

So I use origin image as input, and now I found the clusters are fullfilled.

In conclusion, I suggest you try a larger sample size data, or, just change the cluster number you assigned.